# How to extract a field from each object in an array with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I performed a cURL request to get all the users in our Gitlab server, like this.

```
$ curl -H "Private-Token: a;sldkfja;slkdfj" https://gitlab.domain.com/api/v3/users?active=true > my_file.json
```

and (part of) my_file.json looks like:

```
[
  {
    'username' : 'jdoe',
    'name' : 'John Doe',
    ...
  },
  {
    'username' : 'jadoe',
    'name' : 'Jane Doe',
    ...
  }
]
```

I stored the response in `my_file.json`. How can I use `jq` to get all the `username` values?

```
$ cat my_file.json | jq -r 'what to put here?'
```

Comment: If that is what the actual cURL response or contents of your file looks like, you do not have valid JSON.

Comment: You showed us the source data, what are you wanting the output data to look like?

Comment: @JAAulde, I want an output that can let me parse all the usernames easily.

Comment: Your stated goal is entirely too subjective. Please provide a sample format of desired output in your question.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad request at all. The precise output format doesn't matter - he's obviously trying to grapple with the jq syntax to (as the title says) "extract a field from each object in an array". The accepted answerer clearly figured out what he (and I) wanted.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
$ jq -r '.[].username' my_file.json
jdoe
jadoe
```